# How to creat & deploy react & django project to Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: reactjs, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to creat a web application using React as frontend & Djanog as backend, and deploy that web application to Elastic Beanstalk.
What should I do (separate frontend from backend folder?) to make Easy deployment to Elastic Beanstalk.

I don't find any resource that provide step by step on deployment of React & Django to Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: This may help get you started https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider the frontend with React and the backend with Django as two separate projects, with two different deployments, both on AWS, but with different services.

- the backend, Django, may be on ElasticBeanstalk. Thanks to @p7dxb, you have an [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html) on how to do that.
- the frontend, React, may be on [S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteHosting.html), with [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-s3-amazon-cloudfront-a-match-made-in-the-cloud/).

Different scenarios can lead you to deploy differently. For exemple, with Server Side Rendering, your React App may be deployed in a container on AWS Elastic Container Service. This is a more advanced deployment.